# kvm virtual machine cannot delete a snapshot

Tags: virtual-machine, virtual, qemu, snapshot, kvm

I want to expand the disk capacity of the win7 virtual machine,but it prompts me that there are snapshots and cannot be expanded,but the snapshots cannot be deleted.

```
[root@jwf home]# qemu-img resize win7.qcow2 +30G
qemu-img: Can't resize an image which has snapshots
qemu-img: This image does not support resize
[root@jwf home]#
```

Use the qemu-img command to view the snapshot information.

```
[root@jwf home]# qemu-img info win7.qcow2
image: win7.qcow2
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 40G (42949672960 bytes)
disk size: 64G
cluster_size: 65536
Snapshot list:
ID        TAG                 VM SIZE                DATE       VM CLOCK
1         clean                     0 2019-10-18 14:41:10   00:00:00.000
Format specific information:
    compat: 1.1
    lazy refcounts: true
```

But I can't see the snapshot information using the virsh command.

```
[root@jwf home]# virsh snapshot-list win7
 Name                 Creation Time             State
------------------------------------------------------------

[root@jwf home]#
```

Unable to delete snapshot

```
[root@jwf home]# virsh snapshot-delete --domain win7 --snapshotname clean
error: Domain snapshot not found: no domain snapshot with matching name 'clean'
error: Domain snapshot not found: no domain snapshot with matching name 'clean'

[root@jwf home]# virsh snapshot-delete --domain win7 --snapshotname 1
error: Domain snapshot not found: no domain snapshot with matching name '1'
error: Domain snapshot not found: no domain snapshot with matching name '1'
```

No snapshot information is displayed in virt-manager.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bZ2S.png)

This virtual machine is imported by me,there is no snapshot configuration file

```
[root@jwf home]#
[root@jwf home]# ls /var/lib/libvirt/qemu/snapshot/win7/
[root@jwf home]#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes virsh and qemu see different things. This is occasionally because one of them is blind, and less frequently because one of them is hallucinating. In this case I believe virsh is blind. Try this:

```sh
qemu-img info disk_image
qemu-img snapshot -d snapshot_id disk_image
qemu-img info disk_image
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer,the problem has been successfully solved using your method.

Comment: Thats great news! To help other users who had the same problem you had, mark this answer as “accepted” by clicking the green check mark. That way, they’ll know this method works!